# How to convert text file to lowercase in UNIX (but in UTF-8)

Tags: linux, unix

I need to convert all text to lowercase, but not using the traditional "tr" command because it does not handle UTF-8 languages properly.

Is there a nice way to do that? I need some UNIX filter so I can process this in a pipe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gnu sed should be able to handle unicode. Try

```
$ echo 'Some StrAngÉ LeTTeRs 123' | sed -e 's/./\L\0/g'
some strangé letters 123
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work for Turkish character I . It should be converted to ı rather than i  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Answer (score 4):

If you can use Python then such code can help you:

```
import sys
import codecs

utf8input = codecs.getreader("utf-8")(sys.stdin)
utf8output = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout)

utf8output.write(utf8input.read().lower())
```

On my Windows machine (sorry :) I can use it as filter:

```
cat big.txt | python tolowerutf8.py > lower.txt3
```

Comment: That’s sure a lot of code compared with `perl -CSD -ne 'print lc'`.